# Minimize and restore activity / Fragement

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Voip calling app using kotlin and when call received, it will open an activity called IncomingView. So far so good. But I want to Minimize the activity on back button and can navigate to other pages and shows a green bar or indicator at the top bar (similar to WhatApp/Telegram) that indicates that the call is going on and when i tap there, it should bring back my "IncomingView". (I know and already implemented that i can create a notification and tap on it brings back my activity)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to Minimize the activity on back button

you cant minimize Activity, you can close it. You can "minimize" a fragment in a activity by removing it and later on adding it back - this way its state will not be lost.

If you need to minimize an activity, then I suggest to save its state, then minimize it (call finish() on it), then when you need it back then open it again and it should read its old state and recreate in a same way as it was previously.

Comment: Thanks @marcinj - i tried this ` moveTaskToBack(true)` which moves activity to back. so it is possible it to bring it back without saving of states. because on that activity i have a ongoing call with audio etc. which i need to preserve. like MS Teams/Skype and WhatsApp does

Comment: But moveTaskToBack moves a Task - so you will not see any Activity under IncomingView. I think you should decouple the "ongoing call" state from the Activity, for example to some foreground service.

Comment: I already have a foreground service which handles the incoming call. It will be invoked when Firebase Notification arrives and bring my app to front even if the app is killed. Could you please describe in detail to "decouple the ongoing call in service" ?

Comment: You said " because on that activity i have a ongoing call with audio etc. which i need to preserve" - so I assume that your activity contains some data that cannot be lost - otherwise call will be stopped. By decoupling I mean - moving such data outside your View which is an Activity in your case. In MVVM we try to move all buisiness logic to Model classes, and data is often moved to Repositories.